# Wordpress serving PHP but not CSS or JS

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, wordpress

I'm trying to set up an Amazon EC2 instance to run a Django app and a WP instance side by side, differing only by the incoming URL.

Initially, accessing the site via `mysite.com/wordpress` worked, but I also needed to catch the incoming requests from a subdomain address `blog.mysite.com`.  To do that, I created a `default` file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled and included two virtualhost directives, one of which was

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.blog.mysite.com

   <Directory /var/www/wordpress>
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This created some errors with the other virtualhost, so I restored the default 000-default file configuration and restarted.

Now, accessing `mysite.com/wordpress` takes forever, and even then the CSS and JS files are not loading.  Iside the Firebug Net tab, I can see the HTML response, but the CSS and JS files are not loading at all.

What happened here?

Comment: I know it is not a dev issue, since this occurs with the default wordpress settings.  All I did was download the latest WP tarball, unzip it in my server root, then add the db hooks within t`wp-config.php`  That's it.  No WP code has been touched at all.

Comment: `CSS and JS files are not loading at all` What status code do they throw? 404, 500, 200? Can you access the site at `blog.yoursite.com`? Have you checked the logs from Apache, PHP, & WordPress? If you haven't, you may enable debugging in Apache, PHP, & WordPress as well.

Comment: @Pothi, at the time, they were just timing out after 2 minutes of loading attempts.  So I just deleted the machine and reinitialized with a new instance and implemented the configuration myself.